# Capitalizing hyphenated name

Tags: python, capitalize

I have a script looking like this:

```
firstn = input('Please enter your first name: ') 
lastn = input('Please enter Your last name: ') 
print('Good day, ' + str.capitalize(firstn) + ' ' + str.capitalize(lastn)+ '!')
```

It will work nicely with simple names like jack black or morgan meeman but when I input hyphenated name like `jordan-bellfort image` then I'd expect `"Jordan-Bellfort Image"` but I receive `"Jordan-bellfort Image"`.

How can I get python to capitalize the character right after hyphen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [title()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
print('Good day,', firstn.title(), lastn.title(), '!')
```

Example from the console:

```
>>> 'jordan-bellfort image'.title()
'Jordan-Bellfort Image'
```

Comment: @Kasramvd nice.

Comment: As the documentation says: `title` uses a simple language-independent definition of a word as groups of consecutive letters. So it count "jordan-bellfort" as two words: "jordan" and  "bellfort". Read the doc ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest just using [str.title](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title), here's a working example comparing your version and the one using str.title method:

```
import string

tests = [
    ["jack", "black"],
    ["morgan", "meeman"],
    ["jordan-bellfort", "image"]
]

for t in tests:
    firstn, lastn = t
    print('Good day, ' + str.capitalize(firstn) +
          ' ' + str.capitalize(lastn) + '!')
    print('Good day, ' + firstn.title() + ' ' + lastn.title() + '!')
    print('-'*80)
```

Resulting into this:

```
Good day, Jack Black!
Good day, Jack Black!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Good day, Morgan Meeman!
Good day, Morgan Meeman!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Good day, Jordan-bellfort Image!
Good day, Jordan-Bellfort Image!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.capwords()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)instead

> Split the argument into words using str.split(), capitalize each word
>   using str.capitalize(), and join the capitalized words using
>   str.join()

```
import string
string.capwords(firstn, "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a real problem! It is seemingly easily solved with `.title()` and the like but these suggestions do not solve the actual problem of processing any human name. As in `McCormack`, `O'Brien` or `de Araugo`.

Luckily this is a problem that has been solved. See [`nameparser`](https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
>>> from nameparser import HumanName
>>> name = HumanName('Shirley Maclaine') # Don't change mixed case names
>>> name.capitalize(force=True)
>>> str(name)
'Shirley MacLaine'
```